# Detecting end of character stream

Tags: c

Why is the following loop:

```
for (int i=0; string[i] != 0; i++)
```

Often written as the following:

```
for (int i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

If they would evaluate to the same thing, why would someone use the `\0` in the above? Is there any advantage in that or it is the same thing?

Comment: The ASCII nul-character `'\0'` has the decimal value of `0` -- they are equivalent. [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same thing.  There is no particular advantage.  The `string[i] != '\0'` form emphasizes that we're looking at characters.  But the further simplification `for (int i=0; string[i]; i++)` would work just as well also.

It's similar with pointers.  You can write `p != NULL`, or `p != 0`, or just `p`.  The first form emphasizes that we're talking about a pointer.  But it's a matter of style, not correctness.

Comment: In detail, \0 represents the NULL character. As a literal character, the compiler would emit it per the execution character encoding that the compiler and developer agree upon. The C standard specifies NULL in the notional basic character set and further requires that it be encoded as 0. So, `'\0'` always equals `0`.

Answer (score -1):

`'\0'` is has ASCII value `0`. 
so,

```
ASCII('\0') == 0 // same thing
```

**Edit:**
where:
ASCII(): some function that returns ASCII value. C doesn't have such function (although you can just print char as %d to get its ASCII value).

Comment: What is this `ASCII` function?

Answer (score -1):

The main difference is type. 0 is an int, '\0' is a char. Very old compilers would insert conversion code because of the size difference, so using '\0' was more efficient, but that hasn't been the case for a long time.

Still, some people prefer using '\0' to make the type of the comparison explicit.

Comment: `\0` is an `int` in C. Standard section 6.4.4.4 paragraph 10, and I quote: "An integer character constant has type int." Also, the comparison is performed on `int` because of the application of "usual arithmetic conversions", section 6.3.1.8.

Comment: Now, yes, not for the "very old" compilers I mentioned, or previous versions of the standard that didn't support multi-byte characters. The question was why it's sometimes written one way, and the questioner might have encountered legacy code or code written by someone used to the older ways of C.

Comment: The original ANSI C standard has pretty well the same language, and K&R had the same rules for integer promotion since the begining. I can believe that there were pre-standard C compilers which got it wrong, but I certainly never came across one. (And a compiler which felt the need to emit code to change the size of the integer constant 0 would definitely have quality-of-implementation issues, regardless of its idea of the type of a character constant.) If you have a reference to such a compiler, I guess it would be interesting.